# what alternative to std::not1 is to be used when using std::tr1::bind or std::tr1::mem_fn

Tags: c++, stl, functor

I have a vector of smart ptr of my class Foo:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() : mEnabled( false ) {}

  bool mEnabled;

  bool isEnabled() const { return mEnabled; }
  void setEnabled( bool inEnabled ) { mEnabled = inEnabled; }
  /* ... */
};

typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr< Foo > tFooPtr;

typedef std::vector< tFooPtr > tFooVec;
```

I have this working nicely:

```
 tFooVec foo_vector; // insert couple of elements
 size_t count = count_if( foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(), std::tr1::mem_fn( &Foo::isEnabled ) );
```

But what functional "helper" to use when I want to count_if the "disabled" Foo objects

```
 size_t count = count_if( foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(), std::not1( std::tr1::mem_fn( &Foo::isEnabled ) ) ); // does not compile
```

above line does not compile:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:446: error: no match for call to '(std::unary_negate<std::tr1::_Mem_fn<bool (Foo::*)()const> >) (std::tr1::shared_ptr<Foo>&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:322: note: candidates are: bool std::unary_negate<_Predicate>::operator()(const typename _Predicate::argument_type&) const [with _Predicate = std::tr1::_Mem_fn<bool (Foo::*)()const>]
make: *** [src/shared_ptr_tests.o] Error 1
```

(Using g++ 4.1.2 on Linux)

I think the compile problem comes from the fact that `std::not1` is using `std::unary_negate` which requires that the function / Predicate provided `Predicate::argument_type` . The latter is given when the Predicate is derived from `std::unary_function` *sigh*

Having said this I assume that `std::tr1::mem_fn` is not using `std::unary_function` nor providing the `argument_type`.

The solution I am now using is, that I am now using boost::bind instead of std::tr1::bind

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
using namespace boost;
...
size_t countboost = count_if( foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(), !( bind( &Foo::isEnabled, _1 )) );
```

To avoid complications (and confusion), I replacde the usage of std::tr1::bind with boost::bind throughout my code.

Comment: If you can use more recent compilers (C++11), you can use lambda's instead.

Comment: would love to... can't - the system my code is compiled on is not owned by myself. And to make it worse, my code has to be compiled with xlC as well on AIX. So, I am sticking to "old-fashioned" functors.

Comment: Absurd answer: `size_t count = v.size() - std::count_if( v.begin(), v.end(), std::tr1::mem_fn(&Foo::isEnabled));`. Sometimes the simplest answer is avoiding the problem.

Comment: count_if is just an example... I am also looking to apply remove_copy_if. Maybe I should use that in my example as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!boost::bind(... works for me:

```
  bool test(int i)
  {
    return i < 2;
  }

  TEST( boost_bind_test, negateTest )
  {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(3);

    ASSERT_EQ(2, count_if( vec.begin(), vec.end(), !boost::bind(&test, _1)));
  };
```

Comment: size_t countN = count_if( foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(), ! ( std::tr1::mem_fn( &Foo::isEnabled ) ) );

results in:

    ../src/shared_ptr_tests.cpp:217: error: no match for 'operator!' in '!std::tr1::mem_fn [with _Tp = bool ()()const, _Class = Foo](&Foo::isEnabled)'
    ../src/shared_ptr_tests.cpp:217: note: candidates are: operator!(bool) <built-in>

Comment: @CarstenGreiner Which version of boost do you use? This feature has been added in boost 1.33 which is archaic.

Comment: uh guys - we are not talking about boost in the beginning but std::tr1 - I know tr1 is implemented in boost, but well I am _not_ using directly the boost includes. So, yeah, I have boost 1_44 in place, but here I restrict myself to std:tr1 stuff. (maybe I go and reconsider using boost).

Comment: using now `boost::bind` and I needed to add this template 
    
`template<class T> inline T * get_pointer(std::tr1::shared_ptr<T> const & p)
    {
      return p.get();
    }`
The latter is due to the fact I am using `std::tr1::shared_ptr` (and _not_ `boost::shared_ptr` )

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that `mem_fun(isEnabled)` takes a `const Foo *`, whereas the algorithm `count_if` is passing a `shared_ptr<Foo>` to its predicate.

I'm not entirely sure why that works OK with `mem_fn( &Foo::isEnabled )`, but doesn't work with `not1(mem_fn( &Foo::isEnabled ))`. All I can think is that the extra wrapper introduces a need for a different conversion. But you could just work around it:

```
bool sharedEnabled(tFooPtr x) {
  return x->isEnabled();
}

size_t count2 = std::count_if( foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(), std::not1( std::ptr_fun(&sharedEnabled ) ) );
```